# Why \pdfoutput=1 is not recommended for normal document writing?

Tags: pdf

I read many times that *"using `\pdfoutput=1` is not recommended for normal document writing"* but I can't find any explanation about this statement.

Why is this practice so wrong?

Comment: It's not _wrong_, but it will only work with the pdfTeX engine (that is if you're using LaTeX, the executables `latex` and `pdflatex`), and and running `latex file.tex` then saying `\pdfoutput=1` is the same as just running `pdflatex`, so it's kind of pointless.  Also if some code checks for `\pdfoutput`, your change may break that package, depending what it does

Comment: Additionally it can confuse external tools which invoke latex and then look for the wrong output file.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, do you mean, e.g., `latexmk`? Can you make some example? Please.

Comment: If you use `pdfoutput=1` in a `a.tex` file, then when you run `latex a` you will produce a `a.pdf`. `latexmk` expects a `a.dvi` file from `latex a`, and will try to use `dvips a.dvi` to generate a postscript file, and fail.